# Papyrus Marte Modeling

Tags: papyrus

I am trying to model with papyrus Marte in eclipse, I want to know what is the difference between association navigable in both directions and associtiation navigable in only one direction.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it represents a link, an association has two ends. An association’s end is modeled by means of a UML Property which can be owned by the classifier involved at the related end of the association, in that case the association is said to be navigable as the source classifier can directly refer to the target instance (the instance at the other end of the association) by means of that property. Otherwise the property representing the association end may be owned by the association instance itself.

You can find more details about this topic in http://lowcoupling.com/post/47801917915/understanding-uml-associations